# Export selected ranges to *.txt

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like this one:

```
Date        Réf A   Réf B   Client
21/05/18    AA      BB      Alain
22/05/18    CC      DD      Denise
22/05/18    CC      DD      Denise
25/05/18    EE      FF      Fred
25/05/18    EE      FF      Felipe
25/05/18    EE      FF      Fred
26/05/18    GG      HH      Hugo
02/06/18    II      JJ      Jacky
```

I would like to build a macro that exports me to a txt file (tab separator (it's important)), this table but only on the selected range.

**For example:**

Macro (Date1, Date2), with

**Date1** = 21/05/2018

**Date2** = 25/05/2018

... only exports me the first 6 lines.

I have a piece of code that builds the export on a defined range, but I don't know how to adapt it:

```
Sub Export()
    Dim Plage As Object, oL As Object, oC As Object, Sep$, Tmp$
    Dim FileN As String
    FileN = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("Z1")         'Nom du fichier créé
    Sep = vbTab
    With Worksheets(1)
        Set Plage = .Range("A1:D11")
    End With
    FileN = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test\" & FileN
    Open FileN & ".txt" For Output As #1
    For Each oL In Plage.Rows
        Tmp = ""
        For Each oC In oL.Cells
            Tmp = Tmp & CStr(oC.Text) & Sep
        Next
        Print #1, Tmp
    Next
    Close
End Sub
```

Here I have attached an example:
[image: example image]

- At the **left**: the initial Table
- At the **center**: the Date1 and Date2
- At the **right**: the results

Comment: Should the text file always include the **headers** ??

Comment: Oh yes ! Thank you !

Comment: I think you might be trying to reinvent the wheel a little bit - why not just select the dates you want, copy that by values to a temporary sheet and use the built-in export and choose text file as the output format? It defaults as tabbed spacing

Comment: Hello. What I'm trying to do, is to create an interface for the users. The users will have to select the date1 and date2, and, just on one click, he will get the export in the txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let me know if this works for you. I took the liberty of reformatting your initial code. The big change is that now `Plage` is set based on the date values stored on `Sheets(1)`. The new function `GetRange` tries to match values in column A against the values put in the starting and end date cells.

```
Sub Export()

    Dim FileN As String
    FileN = ThisWorkbook.path & "\test\" & Sheets("Feuil1").Range("Z1").Text     'Nom du fichier créé

    Dim Plage As Range
    Set Plage = getRange

    Dim oL As Range
    Dim oC As Range

    Dim Tmp As String
    Dim Sep As String
    Sep = vbTab

    Open FileN & ".txt" For Output As #1

    For Each oL In Plage.Rows
        Tmp = ""
        For Each oC In oL.Cells
            Tmp = Tmp & CStr(oC.Text) & Sep
        Next
        Print #1, Tmp
    Next

    Close

End Sub

Function GetRange() As Range

    Dim date1 As String
    date1 = Sheets(1).Range("H3").Text

    Dim date2 As String
    date2 = Sheets(1).Range("H4").Text

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim RowStart As Integer
    Dim RowStop As Integer

    With Sheets(1)
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, "A").Text = date1 Then
                RowStart = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, "A").Text = date2 Then
                RowStop = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        'depending on your data, maybe make sure RowStop > RowStart
    End With

    Set getRange = Range("A" & RowStart & ":D" & RowStop)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks ! Very helpful Marc !